# writing a constructor in java

Tags: java, constructor, inventory

This is the assingment i need to do

> Write a constructor that accepts arguments for the four fields, mutator methods for each field, and accessor methods for each field. In addition, write an instance method that calculates the total value of that item of inventory. You calculate the total value by multiplying the numberOnHand by the price, and return the value as a double.

the program has already been lade out mostly but i can't figure out how to make it the way it's supposed to be.

This is what i was given.

```
    public PetStoreInventory(String s, String d, int units, double p) {
    //your code goes here
}

public void setDescription( String s){
    //your code goes here
}

public void setDepartment( String d){
  //your code goes here
}

public void setUnitsOnHand ( int units){
    //your code goes here
}

public void setPrice ( double p ){
    //your code goes here
}

public String getDescription(){
    return "";  //so it compiles, you must change this
}

public String getDepartment(){
  return "";  //so it compiles, you must change this
}

public int getUnitsOnHand(){
    return 0;   //so it compiles, you must change this
}

public double getPrice(){
    return 0.0; //so it compiles, you must change this
}

public double calcTotalValue(){
    return 0.0; //so it compiles, you must change this
}
```

[image: This is the desired output]
The Program in which this output comes from is already made

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working?  "Here's my homework, how do I do it?" isn't really an answerable question.  If you want to learn how to write code in Java then you should start with some Java tutorials.

Comment: Just fill in the blanks. Google what a setter and getter is and you'll be 75% of the way finished.

Comment: Start of by creating the four fields that you need to store the first 4 columns in the tables. In other words, you need to store (String s, String d, int units, double p) in the class itself.

Comment: [This is a good place to start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add instance variables for the four fields, then use these in your code. So in the constructor you would be setting the values for these instance variables (these values will be sent to the constructor generally from another class).

```
private String description;
private String dept;
private int units;
private double price;

public PetStoreInventory(String s, String d, int units, double p) {
    this.description = s;
    this.dept = d;
    this.units = units;
    this.price = p;
}

public void setDescription( String s){
    // set instance var equal to the passed parameter
    this.description = s; 
}

public void setDepartment( String d){
    this.dept = d;
}

public void setUnitsOnHand ( int units){
    this.units = units;
}

public void setPrice ( double p ){
    this.price = p;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return description;  // return the instance var
}

public String getDepartment(){
   return dept; 
}

public int getUnitsOnHand(){
   return units;   
}

public double getPrice(){
   return price; 
}

public double calcTotalValue(){
   double totalVal = 0.0; //initalise a new variable

   /* the next line must calculate the total using the instance
      variables created at the beginning.
    */
   totalVal =?? //to be completed as it is an assignment

   return totalVal;
}
```

Only the line 'totalVal = ??' needs to be completed. Follow the question and use the instance variables and let me know if you need any more help!

Answer (score 0):

Note that it's advisable that after you have a look at this solution to try to do your own one, we learn from mistakes and via training.
I tried to make it simple for your understanding

```
public class PetStoreInventory {
private String description;
private String department;
private int unitsOnHand;
private double price;
private double totalValue;
public PetStoreInventory(String description, String department,int unitsOnHand, double price){
        this.description = description;
        this.department = department;
        this.unitsOnHand = unitsOnHand;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public double calculateTotalValue(){
        return unitsOnHand*price;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
    public int getUnitsOnHand() {
        return unitsOnHand;
    }
    public void setUnitsOnHand(int unitsOnHand) {
        this.unitsOnHand = unitsOnHand;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public double getTotalValue() {
        return totalValue;
    }
    public void setTotalValue(double totalValue) {
        this.totalValue = totalValue;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        PetStoreInventory item1 = new PetStoreInventory("Jack Russel", "Dogs", 4, 359.95);
        String description = item1.getDescription();
        String department = item1.getDepartment();
        int unitsOnHand = item1.getUnitsOnHand();
        double price = item1.getPrice();
        double totalValue = item1.calculateTotalValue();

        System.out.println(description + "\t" + department + "\t" + unitsOnHand + "\t" +price  + "\t" + totalValue);

    }
}
```

result would be for example:

```
Jack Russel    Dogs    4   359.95    1439.8
```